# Is this code as efficient as it could be?

Tags: c, arrays

I've written a function that returns a pseudo-boolean if all elements in an array of a particular length are positive. I feel this may be inefficient:

```
int all_positive(int a[], unsigned int alen)
{
for(int i = 0 ; i < alen ; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] < 0)
            {
                return 0;
                break;
            }
        else if(i == alen - 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmh... maybe this will save some conditional jumps : `int i;for(i = 0 ; i < alen && a[i] >= 0 ; i++);return i == alen-1;` ?

Comment: Is this for PC, and if it is, are you open to using SSE intrinsics?

Comment: @digEmAll `return i == alen-1;` --> `return i == alen;`

Comment: Can you afford to set a negative sentinel in place of testing an explicit length? Anyway, short of getting fancy a `size_t` index might aid the optimizer to unroll the loop on common 64-bit bit platforms.

Comment: The single most effective efficiency improvement would probably be to introduce a variable to keep track of "number of non-negative values" that is updated whenever the array is modified; so that the entire loop can be replaced by `return (someVariable == 0);`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: oops yep, correct :)

Answer (score 2):

You can clean it up and make it shorter:

```
int all_positive(int a[], unsigned int alen)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < alen ; i++)
        if(a[i] < 0)
                return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

I'm not sure if this will be faster. Your optimizer can probably do this too.

Answer (score 2):

```
int all_positive(int a[], unsigned int alen)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < alen && a[i] > 0; ++i)
        ;
    return i == alen;
}
```

You can tidy up the code a little so there is less branching. Also replace `i++` with `++i` so that a temporary object isn't created.

Comment: That is interesting.  why does moving the test into for for loop reduce branching?

Comment: @EvilTeach: because the IF statement has been removed completely.

Comment: @digEmAll doesn't matter, the test is still there. Moving it into the `for`-condition is just a bad attempt at sweeping it under the rug, there are still two branches per iteration.

Comment: You're not correct. That test is compiled to a couple of CPU operations between integers... an IF statement instead is translated to a conditional jump that is much more expensive, in particular if the jump is not predicted correctly by the CPU...

Comment: @digEmAll the test is compiled to a comparison and a branch, at least by GCC and Clang. It *could* be compiled to two comparisons (being a bit sneaky to avoid the out-of-bounds access), then the results combined with some setcc/movcc sequence, and then tested once, but it isn't and even if it was it might not be better. E: evidence, if you're still not convinced: https://godbolt.org/g/QoNHIB

Comment: @harold: yes maybe I was wrong about the test being translated in no jump at all, but I see 5 jump instructions in clang with the OP code ([link](https://godbolt.org/g/SJg4J4)) and removing the else instruction 4 jumps ([link](https://godbolt.org/g/Nw8Jfg)), while in the one you posted I count 3, so less branching...

Comment: @digEmAll ok, there is that, but I feel that's leaving the point behind a bit (branches not in the loop are executed only once so they don't count as much), and it's [not really thanks to the IF-elimination](https://godbolt.org/g/h5pvI5). FWIW, chux' version 1 and 3 really do have fewer branches in a relevant sense, version 1 even gets auto vectorized but of course it has not early exit which is a bit of a shame (vectorized + early out is also possible though)

Comment: @harold: yes, I agree that maybe the jumps might not be the most expensive stuff in this case, my point was just that _usually_ removing IF-statements reduces branching (look at [this](https://godbolt.org/g/gJ1rFD) : using & instead of && remove one more jump and it should work as well IMO). Anyway, I agree that in this case the most expensive stuff is the loop so it's really necessary a benchmark to decide which is the fastest way...(as always)

Answer (score 2):

> if all elements in an array of a particular length are positive.

(OP's code implies 0 is to be considered positive.)

Code could `or` all the values together.  All code is doing is looking for a sign bit.

```
int all_positive1(const int a[], size_t alen) {
  int y = 0;
  while (alen--) {
    y |= a[alen];
  }
  return y >= 0;
}
```

No exit for an early negative, but a tight simple loop.

Works for 2's complement systems.  For other rare platforms, it depends how OP wants to handle `-0`

---

For an early exit

```
int all_positive2(const int a[], size_t alen) {
  while (alen--) {
    if (a[alen] < 0) return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

---

The *classic* hack it to put a known negative at one end.  Of course, `int a[]` cannot be `const`.  Similar to [@technosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443639/2410359)

```
int all_positive3(int a[], size_t alen) {
  if (alen == 0) return 1;
  if (a[0] < 0) return 0;

  int temp = a[0];
  a[0] = -1;
  while (a[--alen] >= 0);
  a[0] = temp;
  return alen == 0;
}
```

Comment: In a couple of cases where it made sense, reserving element 0 for the search key, gives a known sentinel, if you can search backwards.  Then a test whether the found subscript is 0, gives you your answer.   I like the audacity of the or technique.  If alen is small, it might be usable.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `else if` part and do it outside of the loop like.

```
If (i == alen) return 1;
```

Or

```
return 1;
```

That way you avoid checking the condition on every loop. Other than that, I don't see any other possible improvement.

Edit: Also, you don't need the `break;`, since you use `return;`

Comment: @DanielJour I'm sorry about that, I forgot that for a moment. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

- Don't return an `int`. Return a `bool` (available since C99 ... it's 2017 now!)
- `unsigned int alen` vs (`signed`) `int i` ... not a good idea! Be consistent and use the type *designed* for this for both the length and the index: `size_t`
- That whole `else if` is unnecessary. Just place a `return true;` outside the loop at the end of the function. This will also silence the compiler warning you about "control reaches end of non-void function". You do have all warnings enabled, do you?
- Do you modify the contents of the array? *No*, so tell that to the callers of the function: `int const * a` (also get's rid of that mostly confusing syntactic sugar to hide a pointer).
- The `break` is superfluous.

That said, you're doing a single pass over that array, just looking at each element. There are dozens of variations of how to write that simple loop, and all will probably be almost exactly as fast. If you're searching for a performance bottleneck, then this is probably (*) not the place to search for (otherwise you need to try to get SSE or - for large arrays - multiple threads to work on this)

My take:

```
bool all_positive(int const * array, size_t length) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] < 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

---

(*) To be sure you need to *profile* your code. This is commonly done by compiling the code with special compiler switches, such that running the compiled program generates a profile of where in the code the program spends most of it's time. **If** it turns out that above loop is the actual bottleneck, then it might make sense to try to get rid of it as suggested in the comments by just keeping track of the number of negative elements in that array whenever you insert / modify values.

Comment: `Don't return an int. Return a bool` Complete boolshit. The smallest type (on machine level) that can be returned is an int. Bool only exists to attract Java-hipsters. It can also confuse older platforms/implementations that introduce their own strand of Bool.

Comment: @wildplasser The smallest type that can be returned on machine level depends on the actual machine; it could be an `int`, but also an 8 bit wide datatype. But this is mostly irrelevant, because `bool` will help the optimizer a lot, perhaps make it even able to use some CPU flag to convey that information if that function get's inlined. "Older platforms/implementations [..]" ... possibly, but those then **aren't** implementations of the C language...

Comment: bools and const shouldn't have any affect on performance (I'd use them too, though).

Comment: I suggest it would be better to leave array as an array instead of a pointer.  As a pointer one would also have to test against NULL.  returning an int is better as that is normal in c.  bool does work.  It clouds the issue though.

Comment: The smallest type is a machine register. 8086 *could* maybe return chars, but because of alignment reaquirements, char is almost always extended to machine-width int, and truncated to-and fro.

Comment: @EvilTeach `int const * array` and `int const array[]` in a function declaration are equivalent and nobody's forcing you to test for NULL pointers. Your docs can simply declare that if you do get a NULL pointer, "the behavior is undefined". :)

Comment: @wildplasser https://godbolt.org/g/AeS3D4 for just one example where `bool` will be "faster" (though of course only a very tiny bit). The main point though is not the compiler, but to convey information to future readers of the code. Returning an `bool` is completely unambitious here: true -> all are positive, false -> not all are positive. Returning an int could also mean "the number of positive" elements ...

Comment: @wildplasser: Actually the smallest plausible return type is a single-bit flag. Leaving type open to the compiler means that the compiler vendor (or ABI designer) can worry about picking the optimal type. For instance the 8051 compiler which I, for my sins, am presently working with does in fact return a single bit though the carry flag while using a full 16-bit integer would quite inefficient since the MCU only supports 8-bit arithmetic natively.

Comment: No, a bool is not a *real* type,(since there can be no pointer to bool, if represented as a single bit) The smallest addressable type is still a char. Bool is just fluff. IMnsvHO. For the normal case (static functions becoming inlined) the difference is nil. Bool is syntactic sugar.

Comment: @wildplasser: You're missing the point. The ABI is free to use a single-bit flag for the temporary return value precisely because it is not addressable, thereby complying with the as-if rule. Were I to subsequently spill the return value to, say, a global variable then my IAR 8051 compiler would be indeed be forced to spill to a full byte. However for return values, parameters and non-address variables locals the optimizer is free to get fancy with the register allocation for the sake of efficiency. Bit flags happen to be particularly efficient on this architecture, and so that's what is used.

Comment: That behaviour (including inlined static functions) is completely equivalent to returning an int or char (and optimising it away into a condition context). Bool is never necessary. It is only fluff.

Comment: @wildplasser: Well, such an optimization requires the limited value range to be reliably inferred. For interfaces crossing translation units an `int` return value would require sophisticated global link-time optimization to allow a bit flag to be substituted. In dynamic cases, say crossing shared library boundaries, doing so simply impossible. Frankly my particular compiler struggles with cases far less involved than this.

Comment: For what it is worth here is the relevant passage from the ABI specification in question: [IAR C/C++ Compiler Reference Guide](http://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/8051/webic/doc/EW8051_CompilerReference.pdf) - "For all calling conventions, scalar return values are passed in registers or in the carry bit" (bottom of page 181, plus table).

Comment: NOTE: there is no *carry bit* in the abstract machine.

Comment: @wildplasser this increasingly feels like trolling :/ if you don't like to use bool then don't. I'll stick to what that international standard *defining* the C language suggests.

Comment: To the two down voters: is this only about sentiments against bool? If not please leave a comment to indicate how my answer could be improved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify that the input arrray must be const, just leave a padding at the end and do this hack.

```
static inline _Bool all_positive(int *a, size_t alen){
    a[alen]=-1;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (a[i]>=0){
        ++i;
    }
    return i!=alen;
}
```

If you can't use a padding you can save and restore the last item

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified a bit.
Check this code, it will give the same output

```
int all_positive(int a[], unsigned int alen)
{
  for(int i = 0 ; i < alen ; i++)
  {
        if(a[i] < 0)
                return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

And if you can use the bool instead of int then it would be more easier

```
bool all_positive(int a[], unsigned int alen)
{
  for(int i = 0 ; i < alen ; i++)
  {
        if(a[i] < 0)
                return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Did your [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) tell you that there is a problem here?  As you are moving from one element to the next, it may be that a pointer implementation could be faster.

The second if check seems odd.  i might rewrite it like this.

```
int all_positive(int a[], unsigned int alen)
{
     if (alen > 0)
     {
         for(int i = 0 ; i < alen - 1 ; i++)
         {
            if (a[i] < 0)
            {
                return 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Since this is positive we can just keep looking */
            }
         }
     }
     else
     {
         /* Empty arrays imply all are positive */
     }

     return 1;
}
```

There are lots of other things that can be done.
I recommend you use a profiler to determine where your program is slow.  It is a useful skill to have.

Comment: Try this: `int a[] = {1, -1}; printf("%d\n", all_positive(a, 2));`

Comment: @Daniel.  Yes.  I am aware of that.  I am reproducing the behavior of his code, as that bug is not really germane to the question.

Comment: The original code does not "feature" this bug; it test for `i == alen-1` (which is true for the last element), while you test for `i < alen-1` (which leaves out the last element).

Comment: Boy it sure looks like a bug.  I'll test it after supper.  Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Nice catch Daniel.  i changed the test to <= and replicated the bad behavior.